# Javascript, passing a variable into a click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I really can't figure out how I would do this. It's more of a concept question than a code question so I'll just post an example:

```
object = $('#div');

function doSomething(object) {
    //iterates through a list and creates a UL with items in corresponding to that list.
    $(body).append("<li id='clickme'>Hello world</li>");
}

function createModal(object) {
    //creates modal dialogue.
    doSomething(object);
    //more stuff
}

$('#clickme').live("click", function() {
    //I need access to object (not the object declared at first,
    //the object passed into doSomething) here.

});
```

Any ideas how I would do such a thing? doSomething would create a set of LIs and have a parameter passed into it. When those LIs the function creates are clicked, they need to interact with the parameter that's passed into doSomething. Is there a way to bind them or something?

Sorry if I didn't make any sense.

Comment: Surely by declaring the object variable using var object would allow you to use this variable inside the click function?

Comment: cant see your problem, object should be accessible since its global?!

Comment: Why not do `return doSomething(object);` inside the `createModal` function, and the inside the `#clickme` click function, assign it in a way like `var clickme_object = createModal(object)`? You can then access it by calling the variable. If I understand your question correctly...

Comment: It would, but the example I have posted isn't by any means the full code. It's doing some stuff with knockout JS that passes a certain object into createModal.

Comment: You probably want `$('body')`, not `$(body)`.

Comment: It's hard to explain. In the actual code, object isn't being declared explicitly. It's using knockoutJS and dataBind to grab the currently selected item.

Comment: @dystroy - That's my stupid mistake haha. I'm not actually appending it to the body in the real code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [jquery data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function to associate data to your DOM elements. You then can read those data when handling events.

An alternate way, generally not recommended but useful when you build your html in one big pass and don't have an easy access to the DOM elements, and only have strings (or keys), is to add an attribute and retrieve it later using [jquery's attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function. Whenever possible I recommend you to use the data function though.

Answer (score 2):

Store the reference explicitly:

```
function doSomething(object) {
    //iterates through a list and creates a UL with items in corresponding to that list.
    $(body).append(
      $("<li/>", { id: 'clickme', text: 'Hello world',})
        .data('object', object)
    );
}
```

Then the event handler can retrieve the reference:

```
$('#clickme').live("click", function() {
    var object = $(this).data('object');
    // ...
});
```

Also `.live()` is deprecated:

```
$('body').on('click', '#clickme', function() {
```

is the hip new way to bind delegated event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

```
object = $('#div');

function doSomething(object) {
    $(body).append("<li id='clickme'>Hello world</li>");
    $('#clickme').click(function(evt) {
        // Here you have access to `object`
    });
}

function createModal(object) {
    //creates modal dialogue.
    doSomething(object);
    //more stuff
}
```

This might not be enough.  If you are creating multiple links rather than just the single one with id `clickme` you might have to find a different selector to use when you attach the click-handler.  But if you nest the function that way, you have access to the parameter `object` that was used when the click-handler was created.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to declare and attach the handler in a location where the parameter would be in scope, through closures (not tested):

```
function doSomething(object) {
    $(body).append("<li id='clickme'>Hello world</li>").click(function() {
        //object is accessible here
    });
}
```